# Is there a site which simply outputs the latest stable version numbers of php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, versions

I want to write a little app for myself which notifies me if there is a new version of php or mysql but I would need a feed or an xml file to read it from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP.net provides one
http://www.php.net/releases/index.php?serialize=1

An alternative that may allow you to add additional software later is looking into the feeds provided by freshmeat:
http://freshmeat.net/projects/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably subscribe to www.freshmeat.net's rss feed and only react when an even numbered version shows up.