# How do I get Git's latest stable release version number?

Tags: git, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm writing a git-install.sh script:
http://gist.github.com/419201

To get Git's latest stable release version number, I do:

```
LSR_NUM=$(curl -silent http://git-scm.com/ | sed -n '/id="ver"/ s/.*v\([0-9].*\)<.*/\1/p')
```

2 Questions:

1. Refactor my code: Is there a better way programmatically to do this?
2. This works now, but it's brittle: if
   the web page at http://git-scm.com/
   changes, the line above may stop
   working.

   PHP has a reliable URL for getting
   the latest release version:
   [Is there a site which simply outputs the latest stable version numbers of php and mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288206/is-there-a-site-which-simply-outputs-the-latest-stable-version-numbers-of-php-and)

   Is there something like this for
   Git? This comes close: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

Comment: You could continue your current strategy, but also sanity check it by parsing `http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/` and/or `http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary` for the highest number there and check for a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just do this:

```
git ls-remote --tags git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git | ...
```

The location of the public repository is pretty much guaranteed to stay fixed, so I wouldn't really consider it brittle. The output of git-ls-remote will pretty definitely not change either.

The version number should be the last tag; you could grab it with something like this:

```
git ls-remote ... | tail -n 1 | sed 's@.*refs/tags/\(.*\)\^{}@\1@'
```

Comment: Cool, but the person running this script most likely wont have Git installed yet. :) Maybe I could scrape this URL instead:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/refs/tags/
And just find the highest number like Dennis Williamson suggested. Or, maybe better, this URL lists the latest release number first:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/
I think how I'm doing it now is fine though. It works, it's fast & easy, and I think it's pretty reliable.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: Oh, duh. Well... yeah, I guess take your pick of the many many places that display the information, like the gitweb pages Dennis suggested. Those are pretty solidly tied to the locations of the repositories, and I doubt gitweb will ever stop showing tags.

Comment: @VictorSanchez: Yes, I suppose it doesn't deal correctly with two-digit version numbers. (I don't think that'd ever happened when I wrote the answer; they tend to roll over before then.) Pipe it through an appropriate sort if you like.

Answer (score 3):

I use *git-scm.com* for this.

```
latest_git_version=$(curl -s http://git-scm.com/ | grep "class='version'" | perl -pe 's/.*?([0-9\.]+)<.*/$1/')
echo $latest_git_version
```

Very useful when you are on a new box and want to install latest stable git like so:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-${latest_git_version}.tar.gz
tar xzf git-${latest_git_version}.tar.gz
cd git-${latest_git_version}
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Maybe this would also be a good fallback for kernel.org or vice versa.

Comment: Fixed it. Also, I keep a more recent version at https://github.com/felixhummel/x/blob/master/git_from_source.sh.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this on freebsd/bash:

`git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/user/testpro.git | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*refs\/tags\///g'`

Answer (score 0):

I generally just use the `maint` branch. It only gets commits that have been rigorously tested in other branches like `pu` or `next`. It is generally very stable and at any given time is actually likely to contain *less* bugs than the latest official release.

Answer (score 0):

I use  [github.com](https://github.com/git/git/tags) and remove "-rc" versions due to kernel.org reponses unstably.

`curl -s https://github.com/git/git/tags | grep -P "/git/git/releases/tag/v\d" | grep -v rc  |  awk -F'[v\"]' '{print $3}' | head -1`

If you'd like to check the result in bash;

```
GIT_INSTALL=$(curl -s https://github.com/git/git/tags | grep -P "/git/git/releases/tag/v\d" | grep -v rc  |  awk -F'[v\"]' '{print $3}' | head -1)

if [[ "$GIT_INSTALL" =~ ^[0-9]*?\.[0-9]*?\.[0-9] ]]
then
  echo GIT_INSTALL=$GIT_INSTALL
else
  echo "Failed to get the latest stable git version. Quit." 
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Changed to github.com because kernel.org is not stable.